# What is the difference between spatial regimes and spatial heterogeneity?

Tags: spatial-statistics, autocorrelation

Let me cite excerpts from the GeoDA-Gloassary (https://geodacenter.asu.edu/node/390)

Spatial regimes:

> Spatial regimes are a form of spatial heterogeneity, which implies structural differences across space. When a variable is **characterized by distinct distributions (e.g., with a different mean or variance) for different geographic subregions**, these subregions might point to the existence of spatial regimes.

Spatial heterogeneity:

> Spatial heterogeneity exists when structural changes related to location exist in a dataset. In such cases, spatial regimes might be present, which are **characterized by differing parameter values or functional forms**.

Unfortunately, the difference is still not clear to me. Both explanations seem to indicate that spatial regimes as well as spatial heterogeneity refer to a process' variation of mean/variance over space.

Comment: And there was me thinking that legalese was the least clear form of English. a seems to be defined with reference to b and b to a.

Comment: I would typify regimes as a homogeneous regions within a heterogeneous random field. Polygons or clusters of similarly valued points would be examples of regions. I would think that anytime you have a nominal characteristics in a spatial domain you could characteristic it as being regionalized.

Answer (score 1):

***heterogeneity:*** *specifies the diversity of the differences/ non uniform stuff.*

**SPATIAL HETEROGENEITY**: Spatial heterogeneity is a property generally ascribed to a landscape or to a population. It refers to the uneven distribution of various concentrations of each species within an area.

Spatial heterogeneity could be **either local or stratified**

**spatial local heterogeneity** refers to the phenomena that the value of an attribute at one site is different from its surrounding, such as a hotspot or cold spot.

Can be tested by LISA.

**spatial stratified heterogeneity**, referring to the phenomena that the within strata variance is less than the between strata variances, such as ecological zones and land-use classes.

can be measured by geographical detector q-statistic.

The case in which structural conditions have differing effects on some levels in different geographical units leads to what is called the **spatial regime**.
When that variable is characterized by distinct distributions(e.g., with a different mean or variance)for different geographic units, these subregions might point to the existence of spatial regimes.

They are characterized by the different parameter values or functional forms.

> e.g., crime in certain regions might be structurally different from
> crime in other regions